# How to ask Scala if evidence exists for all instantiations of type parameter?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-3, match-types

Given the following type-level addition function on Peano numbers

```
sealed trait Nat
class O extends Nat
class S[N <: Nat] extends Nat

type plus[a <: Nat, b <: Nat] = a match
  case O => b
  case S[n] => S[n plus b]
```

say we want to prove theorem like

> for all natural numbers n, n + 0 = n

which perhaps can be specified like so

```
type plus_n_0 = [n <: Nat] =>> (n plus O) =:= n
```

then when it comes to providing evidence for theorem we can easily ask Scala compiler for evidence in particular cases

```
summon[plus_n_O[S[S[O]]]]  // ok, 2 + 0 = 2
```

but how can we ask Scala if it can generate evidence for all instantiations of `[n <: Nat]`, thus providing proof of `plus_n_0`?

Comment: If the domain is infinite, and there is no relation to any other natural number in testing each case, how do you figure you could get the compiler infer that implicitly?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want something like `given [n <: Nat]: (n plus 0) =:= n`? Wouldn't that be provided anyway, since `n plus 0` always evaluates to `n`?

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "providing evidence for theorem". The type `[n <: Nat] =>> (n plus O) =:= n` has kind `* -> *`, which is not the same as `*`. What do you expect to see as "evidence" for a `* -> *`-kinded type constructor?

Comment: I am trying to translate Coq's proof of [plus_O_n](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html#plus_O_n) to Scala.

Comment: Depending on how you define `+`, one of the two cases `0 + n = n` vs. `n + 0 = n` is much simpler than the other one. I didn't check which one was actually proven in the tutorial you linked. In any case, Coq's proof seems mostly automatic anyway, everything is hidden inside of `nat` definition and the proof-tactics. It doesn't seem like Scala-3 would provide anything comparable, it's not a proof assistant. Anyway, since you mentioned Coq, I quoted a paragraph from the first HoTT-book, except that I extended it with an additional runtime witness to keep it all executable.

Comment: @MarioGalic I've cleaned up the `apply` in `NatInductionPrinciple`, it turns out that the compiler can automatically provide a better alternative to the manually generated runtime witness terms that I constructed previously. I think it's a good opportunity to see on a tiny minimal example what the `erasedValue` and `inline match` is good for: just look how much nicer the `NatInductionPrinciple.apply` is with the `inline match`. This is actually pretty awesome! The trick with `inline match` comes [from here](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/derivation.html).

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Odersky [here](https://youtu.be/Z0w_pITUTyU?t=2060) briefly relates givens to a similar mechanism in theorem provers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one possible approach, which is an attempt at a literal interpretation of this paragraph:

> When proving a statement `E:N→U` about all natural numbers, it suffices to prove it for `0` and for `succ(n)`, assuming it holds for `n`, i.e., we construct `ez:E(0)` and `es:∏(n:N)E(n)→E(succ(n))`.

from [the HoTT book (section 5.1)](https://hott.github.io/book/nightly/hott-online-1287-g1ac9408.pdf).

Here is the plan of what was implemented in the code below:

- Formulate what it means to have a proof for a statement that "Some property `P` holds for all natural numbers". Below, we will use

  ```
   trait Forall[N, P[n <: N]]:
     inline def apply[n <: N]: P[n]
  ```

  where the signature of the `apply`-method essentially says "for all `n <: N`, we can generate evidence of `P[n]`".

  Note that the method is declared to be `inline`. This is one possible way to ensure that the proof of `∀n.P(n)` is constructive and executable at runtime *(However, see edit history for alternative proposals with manually generated witness terms)*.
- Postulate some sort of induction principle for natural numbers. Below, we will use the following formulation:

  ```
   If
      P(0) holds, and
      whenever P(i) holds, then also P(i + 1) holds,
   then
      For all `n`, P(n) holds
  ```

  I believe that it should be possible to `derive` such induction principles using some metaprogramming facilities.
- Write proofs for the base case and the induction case of the induction principle.
- `???`
- Profit

The code then looks like this:

```
sealed trait Nat
class O extends Nat
class S[N <: Nat] extends Nat

type plus[a <: Nat, b <: Nat] <: Nat = a match
  case O => b
  case S[n] => S[n plus b]

trait Forall[N, P[n <: N]]:
  inline def apply[n <: N]: P[n]

trait NatInductionPrinciple[P[n <: Nat]] extends Forall[Nat, P]:
  def base: P[O]
  def step: [i <: Nat] => (P[i] => P[S[i]])
  inline def apply[n <: Nat]: P[n] =
    (inline compiletime.erasedValue[n] match
      case _: O => base
      case _: S[pred] => step(apply[pred])
    ).asInstanceOf[P[n]]

given liftCoUpperbounded[U, A <: U, B <: U, S[_ <: U]](using ev: A =:= B):
  (S[A] =:= S[B]) = ev.liftCo[[X] =>> Any].asInstanceOf[S[A] =:= S[B]]

type NatPlusZeroEqualsNat[n <: Nat] = (n plus O) =:= n

def trivialLemma[i <: Nat]: ((S[i] plus O) =:= S[i plus O]) =
  summon[(S[i] plus O) =:= S[i plus O]]

object Proof extends NatInductionPrinciple[NatPlusZeroEqualsNat]:
  val base = summon[(O plus O) =:= O]
  val step: ([i <: Nat] => NatPlusZeroEqualsNat[i] => NatPlusZeroEqualsNat[S[i]]) = 
    [i <: Nat] => (p: NatPlusZeroEqualsNat[i]) =>
      given previousStep: ((i plus O) =:= i) = p
      given liftPreviousStep: (S[i plus O] =:= S[i]) =
        liftCoUpperbounded[Nat, i plus O, i, S]
      given definitionalEquality: ((S[i] plus O) =:= S[i plus O]) =
        trivialLemma[i]
      definitionalEquality.andThen(liftPreviousStep)

def demoNat(): Unit = {
  println("Running demoNat...")
  type two = S[S[O]]
  val ev = Proof[two]
  val twoInstance: two = new S[S[O]]
  println(ev(twoInstance) == twoInstance)
}
```

It compiles, runs, and prints:

```
true
```

meaning that we have successfully invoked the recursively defined
method on the executable evidence-term of type `two plus O =:= two`.

---

**Some further comments**

- The `trivialLemma` was necessary so that `summon`s inside of other `given`s don't accidentally generate recursive loops, which is a bit annoying.
- The separate `liftCo`-method for `S[_ <: U]` was needed, because `=:=.liftCo` does not allow type constructors with upper-bounded type parameters.
- `compiletime.erasedValue` + `inline match` is awesome! It automatically generates some sort of runtime-gizmos that allow us to do pattern matching on an "erased" type. Before I found this out, I was attempting to construct appropriate witness terms manually, but this does not seem necessary at all, it's provided for free (see edit history for the approach with manually constructed witness terms).